# How to solve NetworkImageLoadException in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to fetch image using image.network(), not getting result, showing error, actually image address will get in api responses,

code look like this,

```
Container(            
    height: double.infinity,
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.18,
   child: Image.network(
   value.recentObservations[index]
  ["thumbnail"],),)
```

and error showing like this,

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
```

How tom resolve this error, comment your references

Comment: You are getting an [http 403 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403). This means that the webserver hosting the image is forbidding you from accessing it. Is `detectpl.com` your own website or a 3rd party website?

Answer (score 3):

This is because your server is not allowing to fetch the image url data. So resolve this from server end.

And you can use

> errorBuilder

in network image to show any default image when your image gets failed to load into specified widget.

You can use below sample code for errorBuilder.

```
Image.network(
   path.image,
   width: 50,
   height: 50,
   errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
        StackTrace? stackTrace) {
     return const Text('');
   },
```